# Refused to set unsafe header "access-control-request-headers" angular 2

Tags: http, post, angular

I'm trying to send HTTP POST to the my server, I do it in this way:

```
var headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Request-Headers': "Content-Type", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
console.log(JSON.stringify(library) + " " + SERVER + "/library");
this.http.post(SERVER + "/library", JSON.stringify(library), options)
  .subscribe(data => {console.log(data.json())});
```

but I'm getting `Refused to set unsafe header "access-control-request-headers"` error. If I'm sending POST without `'Access-Control-Request-Headers': "Content-Type"` I'm getting `Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank in advance.

Comment: Configure the server CORS setting. Add `Content-Type` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: But I did. I have headers in `options` parameter.

Comment: That needs to be configured on the server, not in Angular2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding next code on the server side:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Thanks, [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer)

Comment: hey Sergey need your little help, I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Hi, would you mind clarify what exactly you need? As wrote, I've just added some configuration on the server side and it solved my problem.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to solve the CORS issue. Initially I was getting **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error**. Then I've added *allow-headers* in the server side, and *request-headers* in the client side. Now I'm getting error **Refused to set unsafe header 'Access-Control-Request-Header'**
I added your code in my java file but am getting errors, did you add any dependencies in pom.xml, if yes, than what?

Comment: PS- I'm trying to do a simple login and there are differnet APIs, like *authentication*, *register*, etc. These APIs are on a different port no, and hence are considered on different domain; and my angular code is on another port.
So the APIs are not getting comsumed here. *(that's what I believe, atleast)*

Comment: My case is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864431/cross-origin-issue-in-phonegap-while-consuming-api

Comment: I don't have any 'special' dependencies in the pom. I guess that problem is with authentication's API. **Refused to set unsafe header 'Access-Control-Request-Header'** - it looks like API don't allow using **x-requested-with** and **content-type** headers. Maybe you should consider using another headers based on your aim?